# PHP conditional redirect always redirects to the same page

Tags: php, redirect, dns, conditional-statements

I have two domains and need to make a entry script so i can determine which site the user is coming for and redirect them to the correct part of the site but it just directs to the first link

```
<?php

if($_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] == 'neonbacon.com' || 'www.neonbacon.com') 
{
header("Location: http://neonbacon.com/client");
}
else if($_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] == 'scarletgamers.com' || 'www.scarletgamers.com')
{
header("Location: http://scarletgamers.com/home");
}else
{
echo 'Error 1';
}

?>
```

Comment: `if($_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] == 'neonbacon.com' || 'www.neonbacon.com')` is not a good evaluation. PHP is evaluating `$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] == 'neonbacon.com'` which can be false, but the evaluation of `'www.neonbacon.com'` is always true

Answer (score 2):

It's an order-of-operations issue. You are asking if either

`$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] == 'neonbacon.com'`
 or
`'www.neonbacon.com'`

...is true. The second one will always be true, since it's just a string. So therefore, it'll always execute that `if` block.

Try this:

```
if($_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] == 'neonbacon.com' || $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] == 'www.neonbacon.com')
```

and:

```
else if($_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] == 'scarletgamers.com' || $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] == 'www.scarletgamers.com')
```

Comment: Ah I see now, I'm quite new to coding so that didn't even cross my mind. Thanks :)